# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload()

Tags: php

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap.php:25) in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap.php on line 28**

This is the error my bootstrap file throws, and it's a pretty hard error to solve. I did the basic stuff, check if there aren't 2 classes with the  same name etc. but that wasn't the case. So the thing is: **Whats Next?**

This is the `__autoload` functions I'm using:

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    include_once(BASEURL . DS . 'classes' . DS . 'class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php');
}

$db = new Database();
$data = new Data();
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$functions = new Functions($db);
$users = new users($db, $data, $mail, $functions);
```

**My Questions:**

- How is it possible to solve this error? Especially since there isn't a class which is defined double, and there aren't 2 classes with the same name.
- Is there a way to prevent this error for the next time?

I would like to draw your attention to the fact that I'm a new Stackoverflow user, and I did my very best while asking this question. If you see any improvement that could help me asking my next questions in a way that all Stackoverflow users would agree, please tell me since there's always room for improvement.

Comment: are any of your class files defining a new autoload? Also, your error references lines 25 and 28, which lines are those?

Comment: The error does not say you have 2 classes with the same name but that the function __autoload has been declared twice in bootstrap.php, on lines 25 and 28.

Comment: I'd search all your files for a pre-existing `__autoload()`. There's one there somewhere.

Comment: Try to use [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, thanks to the comments on the OP.

The thing was, I was making use of an `iframe` to load specific content, which also included the `bootstrap.php` file. Thats why it shows that's redeclared twice.

Still thanks for all the comments guys.